# Вывод объекта в цикл

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

вот есть у меня такой объект в котором могут быть до 10 пользователей Вконтакте. У пользователей есть айди, имя, фамилия, фото.

Необходимо вывести в цикл всё это. Подскажите как это делается.

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 288988637 [first_name] =>
>   Александр [last_name] => Алмазов [photo_50] =>
>   http://cs630928.vk.me/v630928637/26da4/wGMdOYhIh7o.jpg ) [1] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [id] => 10404485 [first_name] => Александр
>   [last_name] => Иванов [photo_50] =>
>   http://cs631627.vk.me/v631627485/27bc5/xZXl4GBVcsQ.jpg ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $v) {
   echo $val->id;
   echo $val->first_name;
   ....
}
```

А вообще если в `json_decode` передать вторым аргументом `true` - получите массив, а не объект.

Comment: Просто оставлю это здесь: JSON массив, как правило, передается с названием, например 
`{"sessions":[{"client_id":19733627,"addr":"172.16.96.141","u‌​ptime":730},{"client‌​_id":37268742,"addr"‌​:"172.16.112.95","up‌​time":5}]}`
 чтоб перебрать такой массив нужно сделать так 
`$result = json_decode($array); 
foreach($result->sessions as $res)
   echo $res->addr;`